# Mkdir not working properly - Permisson problem in debian?

Tags: php

my mkdir() function is not working properly on my debian webserver. I have tested this code and it works perfectly fine on my localhost, however it didnt create the directory once I tested it on my server and threw no error or exception.

That's the only piece of the code that isn't working.

```
$url = "../files/object/" . $this->id;

        if (!file_exists($url)) {
            mkdir($url, 0777, true);    
        }
```

All folders are created and the path is correct aswell.

I am aware that this has been asked before, however I could not find a proper solution.

What I want to do: User creates an object => unique directory (name equals id) gets created for file upload

Comment: Without knowing more about the server, how you're running the code, and what effective user is running the code, you will not get an answer here. My hunch is that on the Debian web server the user running the PHP script (likely apache or httpd) does not have permissions to create the directory. You can check the username with this code:  $username = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name'];

Comment: `mkdir()` triggers warnings on failure if I recall correctly. Are you positively sure that your server is configured to log or display them?

Comment: Ok yeah, mkdir() permission denied